# Setting AWS IAM policy for restricting user access to certain EC2 instances

Tags: permissions, group-policy, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to create an IAM policy to restrict the permission of an user to only 1 instance of EC2 instance. 
[EC2 instance description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilYIQ.png)
I created an user and associated that user to a group called "Restricted". 
And then I created a policy and attach the policy to the "Restricted" group.

This is my policy document created for this [EC2 instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilYIQ.png)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1474999077000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:434174043592:instance/i-0b5a42e4827ffc147"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I then open policy simulator to test the user's permission to EC2 actions.

I got all permissions denied. What am I doing wrong? How should I fix it?
Is it possible to allow user access to Billing and only show billing information of that EC2 instance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS has a lot of work on IAM.

This is not supported and you need to put "*" in the resource element of your policy and play with the action element.

See what AWS says about this:

`All Amazon EC2 actions can be used in an IAM policy to either grant or deny users permission to use that action. However, not all Amazon EC2 actions support resource-level permissions, which enable you to specify the resources on which an action can be performed.`

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions) is a list of what is not supported at the resource-level:

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about limiting user access to billing information to certain region or instances? Or is it access to all or nothing?

Comment: Yes it is all or nothing.